# Can anyone spot why my Wordpress loop breaks all the Advanced Custom Fields code that comes after it?

Tags: wordpress, while-loop, syntax-error, advanced-custom-fields

The following loop is running successfully and shows no syntax error in my editor, but it's breaking only the Advanced Custom Fields PHP that comes after it (all the ACF before it works fine, and everything after except ACF works fine).

```
<?php
    $args=array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_parent' => '39'
    );

    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="project" style="background-image:url('<?php the_field('preview_thumbnail'); ?>')">
        <div class="project-overlay" style="background-color:<?php the_field('project_highlight_color'); ?>">
        </div>
        <div class="project-content">
            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <p><?php the_field('preview_text'); ?></p>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="button arrow-right">Read more</a>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; } ?>
```

Here's an example of what still works after it
`<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo-white.png" />`

And here's an example of what's breaking after it (Advanced custom fields code)
`<p class="banner-text"><?php the_field('pullout_summary'); ?></p>`

Sorry if it's a blatant fix! Thanks in advance.

Comment: nothing obvious but what do you mean by breaks? i assume its html errors? If yes you should check the html output to see what is being output.

Comment: Good question. It just display nothing. So in the line of code at the very bottom of my post (pullout_summary), nothing displays in the p tag. It's like ACF hits the end of the loop and stops trying for the rest of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a custom query, you need to restore the global `$post` variable of the main query with `wp_reset_postdata()`. More info in the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata).

Comment: Perfect! Worked a treat. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Holy heck I was losing my mind trying to figure this out. Thanks for this. Saved my booty.